# Why the same mongodb query behaves inconsistently between different client?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, datagrip, navicat

firstly, let's take this simple query as example:

`ObjectId('62663def4e578b0a1cb482c5').valueOf();`

output in DataGrip v2021.3.1:
`{"$oid": "62663def4e578b0a1cb482c5"}`

output in Navicat for MongoDB v16.0.14:
`62663def4e578b0a1cb482c5`

output in mongosh 1.5.0:
`ObjectId("62663def4e578b0a1cb482c5")`

secondly, with `typeof` operator, i.e.:
`typeof ObjectId('62663def4e578b0a1cb482c5').valueOf();`, we can see the data type of the output. they are `object` in both DataGrip and Mongosh but `string` in Navicat for MongoDb.

This is an obvious issue and problematic when developers write complex queries, I believe there must be tickets raised for similar issue(but i haven't found one).

Why it it like this? It could be due to different mongoDB driver version integrated in each client but I searched around and haven't found any solid official documents. Could anyone help on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mongosh and MongoDB JDBC driver that is used in DataGrip have the same core so they should be very similar (and your examples show that. `{"$oid": "62663def4e578b0a1cb482c5"}` is just json representation of ObjectId type).

I don't remember what Navicat uses. I might guess that they have a wrapper for MongoDB NodeJS driver or they directly use old shell called mongo.

I would say that `mongosh` should have the most correct behaviour since it's a new shell that was developed very recently. If you think that this behaviour is incorrect try to create an issue in mongosh issue tracker https://jira.mongodb.org/projects/MONGOSH/issues/

If you think that behaviour of Navicat is incorrect, try to create an issue in their bug tracker

Comment: Thanks. we can see the JDBC driver version in DataGrip, for me it's `Driver: MongoDB JDBC Driver (ver. 1.12, JDBC4.2)`, do you know how to check the driver version used by mongosh and navicat?

Comment: I recommend updating JDBC driver to latest 1.15 version. We fix quite a lot of bugs in each version. You can execute `mongosh --version` in console but this version will not match JDBC driver or navicat. There is a way how to compare JDBC driver and mongosh versions, it's a bit complicated but I think there is no need. Navicat might be completely different driver so version will tell you nothing.

Comment: Thank you. I just upgraded JDBC drvier to 1.15 in DataGrip, the query still returns `{"$oid": "62663def4e578b0a1cb482c5"}`, which is consistent with in mongosh. yep, I believe DataGrip and Mangosh are more reliable than Navicat. :)

btw, do you know any public document about the driver version in Mongosh? just wanna to figure out it.

Comment: Here are mongosh releases https://github.com/mongodb-js/mongosh/releases
and here are JMongosh (Java driver based on mongosh. JDBC driver utilizes JMongosh) releases https://github.com/kornilova203/mongosh/releases
You can match these two roughly by date.

Here are JDBC driver releases https://github.com/DataGrip/mongo-jdbc-driver/releases they say which version of JMongosh they include

Comment: I found another tiny issue in DataGrip with newest driver version. here is the query https://stackoverflow.com/a/73013521/6228210 . 
with project in aggregation, the fields are returned in specified order when it's in Mongosh 1.5 but not work in DataGrip. projecting fields works well in both tool, it returns fields as specified but not in the expected order. with this I believe more as you said "mongosh should have the most correct behaviour". I will raise a issue in https://github.com/DataGrip/mongo-jdbc-driver/issues. Again, thank you for the patience on this question.