# Move "property: value" position in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb

I've been wondering if you could move one field position. For example:

**Current Document:**

```js
{
    user_id: 1234567890,
    coins: 100,
    card: 500,
    username: 'Shin'
}
```

**(Expected Document)** I would like to move the username into this:

```js
{
    user_id: 1234567890,
    username: 'Shin',
    coins: 100,
    card: 500
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- as far as i know project keeps the order we define
- but try it on your driver to be sure, with more fields also
- the problem is that we have to do this for all fields (here are only 4 so its ok)
- but why you need that? in general because its hash-map we dont care about the order

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=62d43866befa88fe45d75ecb)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$project": 
   {"user_id": "$user_id",
    "username": "$username",
    "coins": "$coins",
    "card": "$card"}}])
```

Comment: Thank you for this!, i just wanted to make it look clean and in ordered list

Comment: As I verified, it works well in Mongosh 1.5 but not in DataGrip. Hope this is helpful for anyone who need achieve this effect and cheated by DataGrip. :)