# How can I add a new Field (key with value) below another Field (key with value)?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-compass

Hello I am trying to set a new key below or above another key (field) just to make the documents a little more organized but when I try to use $addField or $set in Aggregations in MongoDB Compass it adds the new key at the end of the document, for example:
I want to add the key "amazing" above the key "something" with value "0",
I use that:

```
{
  "name": "$name",
  "city": "$city",
  "amazing": "0",
  "something": "$something",
  "something2": "$something2",
}
```

but when I try to do that the preview of the compass shows me that the key "amazing" will be added but at the end of the document, below "something2".

If there is a way to do that in Java it would be cool too, please, thanks in advance.

Comment: someone asked something similar [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73012525/move-property-value-position-in-mongodb) i dont know if my answer is the best way to do it, but i think it can work in your case also

Comment: @Takis that actually is what I need but the answer didn't help me at all, the answer says to just use aggregate but in order to use that I need to add something specific like $set or $addFields I think, I didn't quite understand your answer in this question. How could I actually implement that in Java?

Comment: if you want update we can use pipeline updates, aggregation is not the problem, the answer shows that we can change the order(or add field project can add also) by projecting them in the order we like. now about java you can use Document or functions from the query builder (see driver methods, for example there is project method stage)

Comment: MongoDB doesn't have any particular ordered way of storing fields in a document and it cannot be controlled. Only, the `_id` field will be the first field in a document, always. I guess it applies when using Compass or Java or other tools.

Answer (score 0):

As @Takis mentioned with the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73013521/6228210), you can use projections to specify the fields and the order of them. I verified it works very well in Mongosh.

As for java implementation, you may refer to this post which has a an example to help you.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java/sync/current/fundamentals/builders/projections/

Code snippet:

```
Bson filter = Filters.empty();
Bson projection = include("year", "type");
collection.find(filter).projection(projection).forEach(doc -> System.out.println(doc.toJson()));
```